# How to implement jvectormap in angular

Tags: angular, jvectormap

I'm working on an Angular project (ng-version=4.4.6). I need to have a map which will work without connection. I'd like to try jvectormap. The documentation and every exemples I found are shown for Angular.js. As I am not very experimented in Angular, I have no idea of how to implement this library and use it in my project.

Did anybody ever use it in a project and could show me the way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include both jQuery and jVectorMap files just like described in the official documentation inside your index.html

Then inside your component you have to declare jQuery by doing this just `@Component` decorator.

```
declare var jQuery: any;
```

Then you can inside by example `ngAfterViewInit()` add this code

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  jQuery('#world-map').vectorMap();
}
```

Inside you component html file you add this

```
<div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
```

In your index.html

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.css"></link
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.min.js"></script>
```

The thing is that with angular 2 due to typescript you can easily use jQuery or pure JS

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be easier than I expected. I won't be in front of my computer till monday, but I'll try that as soon as possible.

Comment: Great ! Let me know if it helps then.

Comment: Hi. I try to implement the map the way you describe it. But I have an error "jQuery(...).vectorMap is not a function" when I try to call it in my component. Any clue of where can be the problem?

Comment: Did you make sure both jQuery and vectorMap files are included in your index. html file ? Did you just declare jQuery just like I did did above ? Let me give a try by myself then.

Comment: I did all of that. The .js are well charged. The declaration of jQuery is well done in the component file.

Comment: I had some issues using files locally . I used CDN files. I updated my answer. I tried the updated code myself and it is working

Comment: I still have the same issues. But clearly another issue, not related to your answer. So I'll try another question to try to fix this bug.

Comment: Just for information, my issue was coming from the import of the .js files which was done in the index.html AND in the .angular-cli.json, which create a conflict. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

1)Import the following library in your angular project

```
 "ika.jvectormap": "themicon/ika.jvectormap"
```

2) Put the above in package.json and run npm install.
3) Then create a file in src as vendor.ts and paste the following statment in it:

```
import '../node_modules/ika.jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js';
import '../node_modules/ika.jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js';
import '../node_modules/ika.jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-us-mill-en.js';
```

4)Import the following vendor.ts file in main.ts file:

```
import './vendor.ts';
```

5) Import the style file in style.scss file:

```
@import '~ika.jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css';
@import './assets/styles/vector-map';
```

6) Create a custom ventor-map.scss file in your assets folder and paste the below:

```
  $vmap-label-bg: #313232;
  $vmap-zoom-ctrl-bg: #515253;

  body {

    .jvectormap-label {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     border: solid 1px $vmap-label-bg;
     border-radius: 2px;
     background: $vmap-label-bg;
     color: white;
     padding: 3px 6px;
     opacity: 0.9;
     z-index: 1100;
    }

 .jvectormap-zoomin, .jvectormap-zoomout {
     position: absolute;
     left: 10px;
     width: 22px;
     height: 22px;
     border-radius: 2px;
     background: $vmap-zoom-ctrl-bg;
     padding: 5px;
     color: white;
     cursor: pointer;
     line-height: 10px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .jvectormap-zoomin {
     top: 10px;
 }

 .jvectormap-zoomout {
     top: 30px;
 }
}
```

7) Create a directive as vector-map.ts and declare in app.module.ts

```
import { OnInit, Directive, Input, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Directive({
 selector: '[vectormap]'
})
export class VectormapDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
@Input() mapHeight: number;
@Input() mapName: any;
@Input() mapOptions: any;
@Input() seriesData: any;
@Input() markersData: any;
$element: any;
constructor(public element: ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.$element = $(this.element.nativeElement);
    this.$element.css('height', this.mapHeight);

    if (!this.$element.length || !this.$element.vectorMap) {
        return;
    }

    this.$element.vectorMap({
        map: this.mapName,
        backgroundColor: this.mapOptions.bgColor,
        zoomMin: 1,
        zoomMax: 8,
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                'fill': this.mapOptions.regionFill,
                'fill-opacity': 1,
                'stroke': 'none',
                'stroke-width': 1.5,
                'stroke-opacity': 1
            },
            hover: {
                'fill-opacity': 0.8
            },
            selected: {
                fill: 'blue'
            },
            selectedHover: {
            }
        },
        focusOn: { x: 0.4, y: 0.6, scale: this.mapOptions.scale },
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: this.mapOptions.markerColor,
                stroke: this.mapOptions.markerColor
            }
        },
        onRegionLabelShow: (e, el, code) => {
            if (this.seriesData && this.seriesData[code]) {
                el.html(el.html() + ': ' + this.seriesData[code] + ' visitors');
            }
        },
        markers: this.markersData,
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: this.seriesData,
                scale: this.mapOptions.scaleColors,
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        },
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.$element.vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').remove();
}}
```

8) Place the following in the following in the page/component you want to use map:

```
In.html file:

 <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div vectormap [mapHeight]="700" 
      [mapName]="mapName" 
      [seriesData]="seriesData" 
      [markersData]="markersData" 
      [mapOptions]="mapOptions" ></div>
```

In .ts file:

```
  mapName: string;
  seriesData: any;
  markersData: any;
  mapOptions: any;
   defaultColors: any = {
   markerColor: '#23b7e5',      // the marker points
   bgColor: 'transparent',      // the background
   scaleColors: ['#878c9a'],    // the color of the region in the serie
   regionFill: '#bbbec6'       // the base region color
  };


 constructor() {
this.mapName = 'world_mill_en';

this.mapOptions = {
  markerColor: this.defaultColors.markerColor,
  bgColor: this.defaultColors.bgColor,
  scale: 1,
  scaleColors: this.defaultColors.scaleColors,
  regionFill: this.defaultColors.regionFill
};

this.seriesData = {
  'CA': 11100,   // Canada
  'DE': 2510,    // Germany
  'FR': 3710,    // France
  'AU': 5710,    // Australia
  'GB': 8310,    // Great Britain
  'RU': 9310,    // Russia
  'BR': 6610,    // Brazil
  'IN': 7810,    // India
  'CN': 4310,    // China
  'US': 839,     // USA
  'SA': 410      // Saudi Arabia
};

this.markersData = [
  { latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City' },
  { latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco' },
  { latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru' },
  { latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu' },
  { latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands' },
  { latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis' },
  { latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives' },
  { latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta' },
  { latLng: [41.0, -71.06], name: 'New England' },
  { latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada' },
  { latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados' },
  { latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda' },
  { latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles' },
  { latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau' },
  { latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra' }
  ];
  }
```

Note: You need to import jquery in angular.json file first otherwise you'll get jquery error